# Visual Studio MSC++ compiler crash

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2013

I'm implementing a list class in C++, I added some code to the class and every time I build the compiler seems to crash, if I write a basic "Hello World" it compiles cleanly. Here's the source code for the list. If anyone could fine the issue it would be greatly appreciated, it's just making no sense to me, Thanks!

Note: The list is not completed, so if you see bugs and errors feel free to point them out.

using Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate 
Platform Toolset: v120

```
#ifndef _LIST_HPP_
#define _LIST_HPP_

#include <initializer_list>

template<typename ty_> 
class List final {
public:
    using value_type = ty_;

private:
    using uint32_t = unsigned;
    using init_list= std::initializer_list<value_type>;

    typedef struct _Node {
        _Node* _prevNode;
        _Node* _nextNode;
        value_type _value;
    };

    _Node* _begin; //begin points to another Node [delimeter] for iterators
    _Node* _end;   //end points to another Node [delimeter] for iterators

    uint32_t _size; //hold the size of the current list

public:
    //Insert Enumerations
    enum Location {
        BEG,
        MID,
        END
    };

    class Forward_Iterator;
    class Reverse_Iterator;
    class Iterator final : public Reverse_Iterator, public Forward_Iterator;

    //Constructors
    List();                        //Initialize the List with null's
    List(const List<value_type>&); //Copy constructor
    List(const init_list&);        //Pre-Allocate with values to the List

    ~List();

    //Methods
    auto push_back(const value_type&) -> void;  //push 1 value on the back
    auto push_back(const init_list&) -> void;   //push n values on the back

    auto pop_back() -> void;                    //remove 1 value from the back
    auto pop_back(const uint32_t&) -> void;     //remove n values from the back

    auto push_front(const value_type&) -> void; //push 1 value on the front
    auto push_front(const init_list&) -> void;  //push n values on the front

    auto pop_front() -> void;                   //remove 1 value from the front
    auto pop_front(const uint32_t&) -> void;    //remove n values from the front

    //insert various values in a specified location based on an enumeration
    auto emplace(const init_list&, const Location& = END) -> void;

    auto insert(const uint32_t&, const value_type&)->Iterator&; //insert 1 value return added address
    auto insert(const uint32_t&, const init_list&)->Iterator&;  //insert multiple values get the ending inserte address
    auto insert(const uint32_t&, const Iterator&)->Iterator&;   //Insert 1 Node and get the inserted address
    auto insert(const Iterator&, const Iterator&)->Iterator&;   //Insert 1 Node and get the inserted address

    auto erase(const Iterator&)->Iterator&;    //erase and element by Iterator address
    auto erase(const uint32_t&)->Iterator&;    //erase and element by poition in list

    auto find(Iterator&)->Iterator&;     //find an element by Iterator address
    auto find_first_of(const value_type&)->Iterator&;    //find the first of a specific value
    auto find_last_of(const value_type&)->Iterator&;     //find the last of a specific value

    auto empty() const -> bool;                  //check if empty

    auto size() const->uint32_t;                 //get the size

    auto begin()->Forward_Iterator&;             //beginning
    auto end()->Forward_Iterator&;           //ending

    auto cbegin() const->Forward_Iterator&;  //const beginning
    auto cend() const->Forward_Iterator&;        //const ending

    auto rbegin()->Reverse_Iterator&;            //reverse beginning
    auto rend()->Reverse_Iterator&;          //reverse ending

    auto crbegin() const->Reverse_Iterator&;     //const reverse beginning
    auto crend() const->Reverse_Iterator&;   //const reverse ending
};

#pragma region List_Constructors

//Returns: Nothing
//Purpose: Initializes the private data members.
template<typename ty_>
List<ty_>::List() {
    this->_begin = nullptr; 
    this->_end = nullptr; 
    this->_size = 0;
}

//Returns: Nothing
//Purpose: Initializes a new list with the data of another list.
template<typename ty_>
List<ty_>::List(const List<value_type>& CPY_LIST) {
    this->_begin = nullptr;
    this->_end = nullptr;
    this->_size = 0;
        _Node* currentNode = CPY_LIST._begin;
    while (currentNode && (currentNode != CPY_LIST._end->_nextNode)){
        this->push_back(currentNode->_value);
        currentNode = currentNode->_nextNode;
    }
}

//Returns: Nothing
//Purpose: Initialize n positions with specified values VIA initializer list.
template<typename ty_>
List<ty_>::List(const init_list& I_LIST) {
    this->_begin = nullptr;
    this->_end = nullptr;
    this->_size = 0;
    for (const auto& VAL : I_LIST)
        this->push_back(VAL);
}

#pragma endregion

#pragma region List_Destructor

template<typename ty_>
List<ty_>::~List() {
    if (this->_begin->_prevNode)
        delete this->_begin->_prevNode;
    _Node* current = this->_begin;
    while (current && (current != this->_begin->_nextNode)){
        _Node* toDelete = current;
        current = current->_nextNode;
        delete toDelete;
    }
    if (this->_end->_nextNode)
        delete this->_end->_nextNode;
}

#pragma endregion

#pragma region Push_Methods

//Returns: void
//Purpose: Adds a new value to the end of the list.
template<typename ty_>
auto List<ty_>::push_back(const value_type& VAL) -> void {
    if (!this->_begin){
        //create the beginning node.
        _Node* begNode = new _Node{ nullptr, this->_end, VAL };
        begNode->_prevNode = new _Node{ nullptr, begNode, 0 };
        this->_begin = begNode;
    }
    else if (!this->_end){
        //create the ending node
        _Node* endNode = new _Node{ this->_begin, nullptr, VAL };
        endNode->_nextNode = new _Node{ endNode, nullptr, 0 };
        this->_end = endNode;
        this->_begin->_nextNode = this->_end;
    }
    else {
        //extend the ending
        this->_end->_nextNode->_value = VAL;
        this->_end->_nextNode->_nextNode = new _Node{ this->_end->_nextNode, nullptr, 0 };
        this->_end = this->_end->_nextNode;
    }
    ++this->_size;
}

//Returns: void
//Purpose: Adds new values to the end of the list.
template<typename ty_>
auto List<ty_>::push_back(const init_list& I_LIST) -> void {
    for (const auto& VAL : I_LIST)
        this->push_back(VAL);
}

//Returns: void
//Purpose: Adds a new value to the beginning of the list.
template<typename ty_>
auto List<ty_>::push_front(const value_type& VAL) -> void {
    if (!this->_begin){
        //create the beginning node.
        _Node* begNode = new _Node{ nullptr, this->_end, VAL };
        begNode->_prevNode = new _Node{ nullptr, begNode, 0 };
        this->_begin = begNode;
    }
    else if (!this->_end){
        //create the ending to be the previous beginning
        this->_begin->_nextNode = new _Node{ this->_begin, nullptr, this->_begin->_value };
        this->_end = this->_begin->_nextNode;
        this->_end->_nextNode = new _Node{ this->_end, nullptr, 0 };
        this->_begin->_value = VAL;
    }
    else {
        //Extend the beginning
        this->_begin->_prevNode->_value = VAL;
        this->_begin->_prevNode->_prevNode = new _Node{ nullptr, this->_begin->_prevNode, 0 };
        this->_begin = this->_begin->_prevNode;
    }
    ++this->_size;
}

//Returns: void
//Purpose: Adds new values to the beginning of the list.
template<typename ty_>
auto List<ty_>::push_front(const init_list& I_LIST) -> void {
    for (const auto& VAL : I_LIST)
        this->push_front(VAL);
}

#pragma endregion

#pragma region Pop_Methods

//Returns: void
//Purpose: Erases 1 element from the end of the list
template<typename ty_>
auto List<ty_>::pop_back() -> void {

}

//Returns: void
//Purpose: Erases n elements from the end of the list
template<typename ty_>
auto List<ty_>::pop_back(const uint32_t& POP_COUNT) -> void {

}

//Returns: void
//Purpose: Erases 1 element from the beginning of the list
template<typename ty_>
auto List<ty_>::pop_front() -> void {

}

//Returns: void
//Purpose: Erases n element from the beginning of the list
template<typename ty_> 
auto List<ty_>::pop_front(const uint32_t& POP_COUNT) -> void {

}

#pragma endregion

#pragma region Insert_Methods

template<typename ty_> 
auto List<ty_>::emplace(const init_list& I_LIST, const Location& LOC) -> void {

}

#pragma endregion

//Returns: uint32_t or unsigned int
//Purpose: Get the current list's size.
template<typename ty_> 
auto List<ty_>::size() const -> uint32_t {
    return this->_size;
}

//Returns: Boolean
//Purpose: Checks whether the current list is empty.
template<typename ty_> 
auto List<ty_>::empty() const -> bool {
    return ((this->_size) ? (true) : (false));
}

#pragma region Positional_Methods

//template<typename ty_> auto List<ty_>::begin() -> Forward_Iterator& {
//  return Forward_Iterator(this->_begin->_prevNode);
//}
//
//template<typename ty_> auto List<ty_>::cbegin() const -> Forward_Iterator& {
//  return Forward_Iterator(this->_begin->_prevNode);
//}
//
//template<typename ty_> auto List<ty_>::end() -> Forward_Iterator& {
//  return Forward_Iterator(this->_end->_nextNode);
//}
//
//template<typename ty_> auto List<ty_>::cend() const -> Forward_Iterator& {
//  return Forward_Iterator(this->_end->_nextNode);
//}
//
//template<typename ty_> auto List<ty_>::rbegin() -> Reverse_Iterator& {
//  return Reverse_Iterator(this->_begin->_prevNode);
//}
//
//template<typename ty_> auto List<ty_>::crbegin() const -> Reverse_Iterator& {
//  return Reverse_Iterator(this->_begin->_prevNode);
//}
//
//template<typename ty_> auto List<ty_>::rend() -> Reverse_Iterator& {
//  return Reverse_Iterator(this->_end->_nextNode);
//}
//
//template<typename ty_> auto List<ty_>::crend() const -> Reverse_Iterator& {
//  return Reverse_Iterator(this->_end->_nextNode);
//}

#pragma endregion

#endif
```

Comment: You're starting by defining a bunch of reserved names (initial underscore followed by upper-case letter) which leads to undefined behavior. I can't imagine anybody accustomed to C++ finding any of these an improvement in any case.

Comment: Removed all the macro's and it still does the same thing, any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to be sure *which* of the problems in your code is giving VC++ such grief, but a few of the most obvious include:

1. Using `_Node` (initial underscore followed by capital letter means this name is reserved).
2. Attempting to declare `Iterator` as being derived from both `Forward_Iterator` and `Reverse_Iterator`, without having defined either of those base classes (what you have are declarations, not definitions).
3. Having a `typedef` that doesn't actually declare a name.

Such as this:

```
typedef struct _Node {
    _Node* _prevNode;
    _Node* _nextNode;
    value_type _value;
};
```

Using a `typedef` for a case like this is a leftover from C anyway. You almost certainly want just:

```
struct _Node {
    _Node* _prevNode;
    _Node* _nextNode;
    value_type _value;
};
```

With those fixed, the code should at least stand a lot better chance of compiling.

If you also get rid of the useless `this->` noise, it might even start to look like real C++ instead of a warped version of Java or something.

To further that notion, you should also start to use member initialization lists, such as replacing:

```
template<typename ty_>
List<ty_>::List() {
    _begin = nullptr; 
    _end = nullptr; 
    _size = 0;
}
```

... with:

```
template<typename ty_>
List<ty_>::List() : _begin(nullptr), _end(nullptr), _size(0)
{}
```

Comment: I was taking things out to try and deduce the problem and it seemed to be the iterators, so I'm going to implement them a different way, thanks very much for your efforts and recommendations I'll keep them in mind.